# Matlab: Shifting a graph (setting a different start position)

Tags: matlab, plot, 2d

I am working with this code to import a spread sheet containing x (angle) and y (intensity) axes and plot the results:

```
%% Initialize variables
filename = ['C:\Users\themosawi\Desktop\khalifadec2104\mih10distracks-azi\mih10-distal-2_5mmbelowDH\mih10distracks_0363.dat'];
startRow = 5;

%% Format string for each line of text:
formatSpec = '%14f%f%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', '', 'WhiteSpace', '', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
angle = dataArray{:, 1};
intensity = dataArray{:, 2};

%% Plot
plot(angle, intensity)
```

Sometimes I get plots looking like this (in which the plotting starts at the middle of the peak):

[image: plot]

I would like the plotting to start from angle 45 instead of angle 0 (in the x-axis) so I can identify both peaks.

Here is the file:
http://mosawi.co.uk/mih10distracks_0363.dat

Comment: I have just edited my answer. It didn't work because 45 degree doesn' t exist in your angle data. I find the point 45.5 degree instead of 45 degree and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it may work:

```
%% Initialize variables
filename = ['C:\Users\themosawi\Desktop\khalifadec2104\mih10distracks-azi\mih10-distal-2_5mmbelowDH\mih10distracks_0363.dat.txt'];
startRow = 5;

%% Format string for each line of text:
formatSpec = '%14f%f%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', '', 'WhiteSpace', '', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
angle = dataArray{:, 1};
intensity = dataArray{:, 2};

%% New angle & Intensity
lap = 100; % // Enter any angle value in range of your angle data
ind = find(angle > lap -.4 & angle < lap + .6);
newAngle = linspace(angle(ind), angle(ind)+angle(end), length(angle));
newIntensity = [intensity(ind:end); intensity(1:ind-1)]; 

%% Plot
plot(newAngle, newIntensity)
```

What I got as output:
[image]

Comment: Error using plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.

Error in Untitled (line 28)
plot(newAngle, newIntensity)

Comment: @Mosawi - I have just edited my answer. I have changed the newAngle definition. Try this one..

Comment: Just one more question, how about if i decide to change the start angle say 50 or 100 instead of 45, is there away to do this with your great code?

Comment: @Mosawi - I have just edited my answer. Now you can change the start angle to any value from your angle data you want. Thank you for compliment, but my code isn' t great actually, just looks simple and works just in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I got your question right, but this is what I would do to phase shift this plot:

If so, you could replace:
%% Plot

```
plot(angle, intensity)
```

with

```
%% Plot
shift_angle = 45;
plot(angle, [intensity(shift_angle:end) ; intensity(1:shift_angle-1)])
```

Comment: Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being
concatenated are not consistent.

Error in Untitled (line 23)
plot([angle(shift_angle:end)
angle(1:shift_angle-1)],
[intensity(shift_angle:end)
intensity(1:shift_angle-1)])

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your variables were column vectors. I have edited the arguments for plot.

Comment: Yes should keep angle as is, re-edited my answer. Anyway, Mehmet answer is better as it shifts the x-axis appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, working with the cyclical nature of the data:

```
angle = angle(:).';             % ensures that these are both row
intensity = intensity(:).';     % vectors (may be unnecessary)

plot( [ angle-360 angle angle+360 ], [ intensity intensity intensity ] )
xlim( [0 360] + 45 )            % or +/- whatever you want
```